# D-Bus: Performance improvement practices

Tags: dbus

**What are some good practices to obtain better time performance in applications that heavily utilize [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)?**

Here are a few that our team has learned through the school of hard knocks:

- Try to combine data entities together into a single, large structure/object to send over D-Bus IPC.
- Try to have all D-Bus traffic come into a single proxy at a single point in your application/process, rather than having them spread throughout your application/process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been a couple of good talks on this subject by the developer of [Bustle](http://willthompson.co.uk/bustle/) which is a tool to help you visualise and measure the D-Bus performance of your application **and** the services its talking too.

- [Profiling and Optimizing D-Bus APIs](http://willthompson.co.uk/talks/profiling-and-optimizing-d-bus-apis.pdf)
- [The Slothful Ways of D-Bus](http://willthompson.co.uk/talks/the-slothful-ways-of-d-bus.pdf)

There is also some [D-Bus API design documentation](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-api-design.html#api-design) which discusses how to design performant D-Bus APIs. The most important principle is to reduce the number of round-trips your API requires clients to make.